# How do I run a filter function on a RDD and create output using different dataframe schemas in one pass

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a proprietary binary format (rosbags) with spark which requires doing some  deserialization. Once that is done, I get data with a fixed number of different schemas. I want to write output files, one for each of the different schemas.

I've managed to create a dataFrame for each schema by filtering by type and deserializing, but all the original data gets read repeatedly.

The below example demonstrates the problem using `json.loads()` for the input and `collect()` for the output.

```py
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def transform(data):
    print("transforming", data)
    return json.loads(data[1])

def filter_by_type(data, type_):
    print("filtering %s == %s" % (data[0], type_))
    return data[0] == type_

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

dd = sc.parallelize([
    ['type1', '"string1"'],
    ['type2', '2'],
])

print(spark.createDataFrame(dd.filter(lambda x: filter_by_type(x, "type1")).map(transform), StringType()).collect())
print(spark.createDataFrame(dd.filter(lambda x: filter_by_type(x, "type2")).map(transform), IntegerType()).collect())
```

Output

```
filtering type1 == type1
transforming ['type1', '"string1"']
filtering type2 == type1
[Row(value='string1')]
filtering type1 == type2
filtering type2 == type2
transforming ['type2', '2']
[Row(value=2)]
```

Comment: I think that unless you have a way to filter out the wanted string without parsing it you have to parse all the data every time you filter. you could use caching (add ".cache" after the "map(transform)") for better performance

Comment: Apologies, my example was oversimplified. It _is_ actually possible to filter before deserializing. The real problem is that the original dataset still gets read over and over again. I've updated the example to reflect reality a bit better.

Comment: As Ever said just cache the RDD(dd.cache()) after you create it, so it isn't read over and over

Comment: Caching is going to be problematic, the original files weigh at hundreds of GiB.